# CodeClimate Coverage error: fatal: Not a git repository - this is a git repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems, simplecov, code-climate

full output:

```
 rspec
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
..........................

Deprecation Warnings:

RSpec::Core::Configuration#treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values= is deprecated, it is now set to true as default and setting it to false has no effect.

Requiring `rspec/autorun` when running RSpec via the `rspec` command is deprecated. Called from /home/lprestonsegoiii/Development/authorizable/spec/spec_helper.rb:11:in `require'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

2 deprecation warnings total

Finished in 0.65367 seconds (files took 1.06 seconds to load)
26 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 9981

Coverage = 84.31%. fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/lprestonsegoiii/Development/authorizable/spec/rails_app/.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/lprestonsegoiii/Development/authorizable/spec/rails_app/.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/lprestonsegoiii/Development/authorizable/spec/rails_app/.git'
Code Climate encountered an exception: CodeClimate::TestReporter::InvalidPayload
A git commit timestamp was not found in the test report payload
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/codeclimate-test-reporter-0.4.4/lib/code_climate/test_reporter/payload_validator.rb:16:in `validate'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/codeclimate-test-reporter-0.4.4/lib/code_climate/test_reporter/payload_validator.rb:11:in `validate'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/codeclimate-test-reporter-0.4.4/lib/code_climate/test_reporter/formatter.rb:21:in `format'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/simplecov-0.9.1/lib/simplecov/result.rb:46:in `format!'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/simplecov-0.9.1/lib/simplecov/configuration.rb:158:in `block in at_exit'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/simplecov-0.9.1/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:54:in `call'
/home/lprestonsegoiii/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/simplecov-0.9.1/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

my code is here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/authorizable

and here is my spec_helper:

require "rubygems"
    require "bundler/setup"

```
require "pry-byebug" # binding.pry to debug!

# Coverage
require "codeclimate-test-reporter"
ENV['CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN'] = ""
CodeClimate::TestReporter.start

require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl'



# This Gem
require "authorizable"

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/support/**/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }


# This file was generated by the `rspec --init` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# Require this file using `require "spec_helper"` to ensure that it is only
# loaded once.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run :focus

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = 'random'

  config.before(:each) do |x|
    $example_definitions.call
  end

  config.after(:each) do |x|
    # reset class variable
    Authorizable::Permissions.definitions = {}
  end
end
```

what's going on here? what's the root of the problem and why does the coverage reporter even care what's in my spec/ directory (when files don't end in _spec).

is there some sort of filter I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ruby-test-reporter 0.4.4 and is reported at https://github.com/codeclimate/ruby-test-reporter/issues/64

Comment: that explains things. haha. thanks. I guess I'll just wait for them to fix it.